# Change the Hard Drive in RAID using tw_cli while lustre file system is mounted

Tags: linux, raid, 3ware, lustre

I've setup RAID-5 array disk, but recently one of the Hard drives is reallocating excessive sectors:

**(Reallocated Sectors = 323)**

```
# tw_cli /c0/p1 show all

/c0/p1 Status = OK
/c0/p1 Model = ST31000340NS
/c0/p1 Firmware Version = SN05
/c0/p1 Serial = 9QJ17SNX
/c0/p1 Capacity = 931.51 GB (1953525168 Blocks)
/c0/p1 Reallocated Sectors = 323
/c0/p1 Power On Hours = 49638
/c0/p1 Temperature = 24 deg C
/c0/p1 Spindle Speed = 14464 RPM
/c0/p1 Link Speed Supported = 1.5 Gbps
/c0/p1 Link Speed = 1.5 Gbps
/c0/p1 NCQ Supported = Yes
/c0/p1 NCQ Enabled = Yes
/c0/p1 Identify Status = N/A
/c0/p1 Belongs to Unit = u0
```

However, as you see below there is no problem in the RAID, and the lustre filesystem has been mounted on it, and is working properly now:

```
# tw_cli /c0 show

Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-5    OK             -       -       64K     6519.19   ON     OFF

Port   Status           Unit   Size        Blocks        Serial
---------------------------------------------------------------
p0     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ18Q8Y
p1     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ17SNX
p2     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    5QJ0DBNE
p3     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ17NBC
p4     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ0GWYX
p5     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ18PKS
p6     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ0YZCD
p7     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    9QJ186K9
```

Now, I want to replace the p1 before something bad happens, and I want to do it without umount the filesystem (I mean Hot Replace). Is it going to be possible?

Comment: In theory, the removal isn't a question, nor the replacement.  You're looking for the documentation on how to add a disk to a degraded array.  From http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/tw_cli.8.html , /cx set autorebuild looks good, or /cx/ux start rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unmount your filesystem while you are replacing a disk on a 3ware controller.
Be careful your write cache will be disable on the unit until the unit is rebuild. So you can have degraded performance. You can adjust the rebuild rate to deal with.

Use the tw_cli documentation to help you adding the disk if you haven't got autorebuild enabled. If the new disk has already been used on a 3ware controller, you ll have some tasks to do like deleting the old unit of the new disk.